# removing elements from html using BeautifulSoup and Python 3

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from the web and trying to remove all elements that have tag 'div' and class 'notes module' like this html below:

```
        <div class="notes module" role="complementary">
  <h3 class="heading">Notes:</h3>
    <ul class="associations">
        <li>
          Translation into Русский available: 
            <a href="/works/494195">Два-два-один Браво Бейкер</a> by <a rel="author" href="/users/dzenka/pseuds/dzenka">dzenka</a>, <a rel="author" href="/users/La_Ardilla/pseuds/La_Ardilla">La_Ardilla</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <blockquote class="userstuff">
      <p>
  <i>Warnings: numerous references to and glancing depictions of combat, injury, murder, and mutilation of the dead; deaths of minor and major original characters. Numerous explicit depictions of sex between two men.</i>
</p>
    </blockquote>
    <p class="jump">(See the end of the work for <a href="#children">other works inspired by this one</a>.)</p>
</div>
```

source is here: view-source:http://archiveofourown.org/works/180121?view_full_work=true

I'm struggling to even find and print the elements I want to delete. So far I have:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://archiveofourown.org/works/180121?view_full_work=true'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
removals = soup.find_all('div', {'id':'notes module'})
for match in removals:
    match.decompose()
```

but removals returns an empty list. Can you help me select the entire div element that I've shown above so that I can select and remove all such elements from the html?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The div you are trying to find has`class = "notes module"`, yet in your code you are trying to find those divs by `id = "notes module"`. 
Change this line:

```
removals = soup.find_all('div', {'id':'notes module'})
```

To this:

```
removals = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'notes module'})
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I'm still getting an empty list though.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a go. It will kick out all available `divs` from that webpage under `class='wrapper'`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('http://archiveofourown.org/works/180121?view_full_work=true')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select(".wrapper"):
    [elem.extract() for elem in item("div")]
    print(item)
```